# Can't get Doctrine form to work in Zend 2

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, annotations

I'm trying to figure out how to use the annotations in Zend along with the Doctrine hydrators and builders and can't seem to figure out where things are going wrong. I have two Entities set up, one called 'Lists' and one called 'Listtypes'. Listtypes defines what kind of list the list is (allows me to create lists in categories). I was initially trying to use the 'ComposedObject' annotation but decided I would rather use the annotations in the Listype object to add/edit those items rather than as a means of getting a select list for the Lists form as a fieldset. So I've tried playing with both a fieldset, and now I'm just excluding both the ListtypeId (referencedColumnName) and listtype (object from the ManyToOne relationship) in the annotations and manually adding the selector after the Doctrine FormBuilder creates the form from the other fields:

```
    $list = new \Application\Entity\Lists();

    $builder = new \DoctrineORMModule\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder( $this->getEntityManager());
    $form = $builder->createForm( $list );
    $form->setHydrator(new \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject($this->getEntityManager(),'Application\Entity\Lists'));

    $form->add(
        array(
            'name' => 'ListtypeId',
            'type' => 'DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\DoctrineEntity',
            'options' => array(
                'label'          => 'Select List Type',
                'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
                'target_class'   => 'Application\Entity\Listtypes',
                'property'       => 'ListtypeId',
                'label_generator' => function($targetEntity) {
                    return $targetEntity->getListtypeId() . ' - ' . $targetEntity->getListtypeName();
                },
                'display_empty_item' => true,
                'empty_item_label'   => '---',
                'find_method' => array(
                    'name'   => 'findBy',
                    'params' => array(
                        'criteria' => array(),
                        'orderBy'  => array('ListtypeId' => 'ASC'),
                    ),
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                    'required' => 'required'
                )
            ),
        )
    );
```

I have this all working great and think I understand what it's doing. It's trying to persist the result that is giving me fits now. I have this selector returning the ListtypeId obviously, so I end up with two relevant parameters coming back, ListName and ListtypeId:

```
    $form->bind($list);

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        $data['ListName'] = $this->request->getPost('ListName');
        $data['ListtypeId'] = intval($this->request->getPost('ListtypeId'));

        $listId = $this->request->getPost('ListId');
        if((intval($listId) > 0) && ($listId != $list->getId())) {
            $data['ListId'] =  $this->request->getPost('ListId');
        }

        $form->setData($data);
        //$this->getDefMapper()->setListtype($list,$Listtype['ListtypeId']);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDefMapper()->getEntityManager()->persist($list);
            $this->getDefMapper()->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }
```

The result of this is an array that includes the name I typed in, and the id from the selector. All appears good. So I do a  $form->setData($data); - no errors, and looking at the $list object, Name is set and ListtypeId is set, but the hydrator has not created an object for the $listtype property (I thought it was supposed to do this - do I also have to set a key for 'listtype' or otherwise set it myself such as with the commented out line of code?)

Now, the thing that has me scratching my head is that as I say, ListtypeId has a value of '2' in the $list instance when I inspect the code in xdebug prior to the persist. But when the persist fires, what I get back is:

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException
File:
R:\TheWild\ZF2Skel\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php:112
Message:
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Lists (ListtypeId, ListName) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, "hoodoo"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ListtypeId' cannot be null
```

What I want to know is, why? It appears to be set when the persist is called.

Comment: With more playing I was able to get it to work, but I still don't understand all the 'whys' involved. I renamed the field from ListtypeId to simply 'listtype' to match the object handle property name rather than the Id field. The result was that the hydrator populated the listitem object handle in $list with an instance of the appropriate Listtypes record. But ListtypeId was still blank. The persist() call then worked. So Doctrine doesn't populate the reference until you persist?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a records in your database with a specific `ListtypeId` that you set manualy.

The message is clear :

> Message:
> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Lists (ListtypeId, ListName) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, "hoodoo"]:

The value of `ListtypeId` is `null`, this is because Doctrine egnors it and continue to generate an ID to your entity as always.

So you need to set the ID of your entity before you call the `persist` method, and also change the `generator strategy`. Just add this code, it should work :

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
        $list->setListtypeId($data['ListtypeId']);
        $em->getClassMetaData(get_class($list))
           ->setIdGenerator(new \Doctrine\ORM\Id\AssignedGenerator());

        $this->getDefMapper()->getEntityManager()->persist($list);
        $this->getDefMapper()->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

See [Force entity  ID on persist](http://www.ens.ro/2012/07/03/symfony2-doctrine-force-entity-id-on-persist/).